# XSL syntax to only copy with more than one word

Tags: xslt

I have large XML files that must be trimmed to exclude specific nodes, and use xsl:template match statements to identify some for exclusion.

But what syntax can I use to exclude or include based on number of words?

Example: this is used to exclude string nodes where the content of instring is identical to the content of outstring

```
<xsl:template match="string[instring=outstring]"/>
```

I need to change that to only match if it is also the case that there is more than one word in instring and outstring.

Pseudo syntax now is: exclude string nodes where instring = outstring
Pseudo syntax needed is: exclude string nodes where instring = outstring AND instring/outstring is more than one word   (i.e. keep those identical strings, if they are just one word)

Answer (score 1):

Could you just check if **instring** contains a space in this case?

```
<xsl:template match="string[instring=outstring][contains(instring, ' ')]"/>
```